# Native Crash: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: [thread] using JNIEnv* from [thread]

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-runtime

The following is the stacktrace. The source code where the crash originates is [here](https://github.com/hashcube/native-android/blob/hc/TeaLeaf/jni/platform/navigator.cpp#L29).

I traced the stacktrace until android's source code which is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/nougat-dev/runtime/check_jni.cc#1185).

I'm unable to understand what this means and why it happens only sometimes. Any help would be appreciated. Happy to share more details.

We have been able to reproduce this crash on an android 7.0 device. But it isn't consistent.

```
06-28 19:09:26.147  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-28 19:09:26.147  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : Native Crash TIME: 265472
06-28 19:09:26.147  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-28 19:09:26.148  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Karbonn/K9_Smart_Eco/K9_Smart_Eco:7.0/NRD90M/1498048597:user/release-keys'
06-28 19:09:26.148  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
06-28 19:09:26.148  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
06-28 19:09:26.148  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : pid: 5587, tid: 5689, name: JS Thread  >>> com.hashcube.sqmtest <<<
06-28 19:09:26.149  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-28 19:09:26.152  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[54,tid=5689,Native,Thread*=0x8a4de500,peer=0x12dc89d0,"JS Thread"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[54,tid=5689,Native,Thread*=0x8a4de500,peer=0x12dc89d0,"JS Thread"]'
06-28 19:09:26.152  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00001639  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
06-28 19:09:26.152  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     r4 899ff978  r5 00000006  r6 899ff920  r7 0000010c
06-28 19:09:26.152  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000000  r9 add696a4  sl 00000ac4  fp add2eecf
06-28 19:09:26.153  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     ip 0000000b  sp 899feb50  lr b039a597  pc b039cdf4  cpsr 20070010
06-28 19:09:26.192  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :
06-28 19:09:26.192  5696  5696 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00049df4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00047593  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001d855  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000193a1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017014  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
06-28 19:09:26.193  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 003188f5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000b4e79  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+864)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00238971  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1664)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00238b63  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+58)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000ca81b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+46)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000ca305  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+104)
06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 000c941f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+26)
06-28 19:09:26.195  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 000c88fb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+802)
06-28 19:09:26.195  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 000cdd79  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI8GetFieldEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP9_jfieldIDbNS_9Primitive4TypeE+496)
06-28 19:09:26.195  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 000c2eef  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11GetIntFieldEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP9_jfieldID+42)
06-28 19:09:26.195  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 0009a35c  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/lib/arm/libtealeaf.so (_Z19navigator_info_initv+252)
06-28 19:09:26.195  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 00084ca0  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/lib/arm/libtealeaf.so (_Z25js_navigator_get_templatev+100)
06-28 19:09:26.196  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 0007caf0  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/lib/arm/libtealeaf.so (init_js+740)
06-28 19:09:26.196  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #18 pc 00089dc4  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/lib/arm/libtealeaf.so (core_init_js+36)
06-28 19:09:26.196  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #19 pc 00099a28  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/lib/arm/libtealeaf.so (Java_com_tealeaf_NativeShim_initJS+180)
06-28 19:09:26.196  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #20 pc 0088494d  /data/app/com.hashcube.sqmtest-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x82e000)
```

Comment: What is your package name?

Comment: com.hashcube.sqmtest. Why ?

Comment: I can not tell now what is the reason but I will try to compile it with lower NDK versions 9, 10, 11, etc.

Comment: Issue can be cause by `Google Maps` but not necesarly. Some developers reported that crash was happening because of `TextureView`, some because of `ViewPager` etc. You can see on issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37123764

Comment: JNI errors are always tricky, you simply need to match the signatures or need to look from which thread you are calling JNI methods, It should be called from the same thread.

Comment: do you call this function from native thread or from java thread?

Comment: @DanielVlasenko I'm unsure about it. It is a framework that we use, but the source is all open -> https://github.com/hashcube/native-android/

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you function is called from native thread and it leads to crashes of call to FindClass and other JNI methods which tries to work with java code

> 06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000ca81b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+46)
>
> 06-28 19:09:26.194  5696  5696 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000ca305  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+104)

In your code in file jni/platform/native_shim.cpp I can see:

```
static JNIEnv* get_env() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    static_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
    return env;
}

native_shim *get_native_shim() {
    if(shim.instance == NULL) {
        LOG("{native} ERROR: Tried to get native shim when there wasn't one");
#if DEBUG
        *((int*)0) = -1;
#else
        exit(1);
#endif
    }
    shim.env = get_env();
    return &shim;
}
```

In line `static_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);` you try to attach current thread to JVM with null JNIEnv pointer. You've declared it, but never assigned. I was looking for **JNI_OnLoad** function in your files but didn't find it. It's good practice to get JavaVM once in this method and store it somewhere, so you can get JNIEnv pointer from it where you need.It could be function like following:

```
JavaVM *java_machine;
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
   java_machine = vm;
}
int get_env(JNIEnv **g_env) {
    int getEnvStat = java_machine->GetEnv((void **) g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if (java_machine->AttachCurrentThread(g_env, nullptr) != 0) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "GetEnvironmentRoutine", "FAILED ATTACH THREAD");
            return 2; //Failed to attach
        }
        return 1; //Attached. Need detach
    }
    return 0;//Already attached
}
```

And you must call `java_machine->DetachCurrentThread();` in the end of method, because if attached native thread exits without detaching, it will cause java machine crash.

You also could write RAII wrapper for this to be shure that your thread been detached on all method branches.

```
class attached_env final {
public:
    attached_env() {
        auto resCode = get_env(&mEnv);
        if (resCode == 2)
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot retrieve JNI environment");
        needDetach = (resCode == 1);
    }

    ~attached_env() {
        if (needDetach) {
            java_machine->DetachCurrentThread();
        }
    }

    JNIEnv *env() const noexcept {
        return mEnv;
    }

private:
    JNIEnv *mEnv;
    bool needDetach;
};

template<typename Callable>
auto call_in_attached_thread(Callable func) {
    attached_env env;
    return func(env.env());
}
```

So your method could look like this (need to precise, see below):

```
navigator_info* navigator_info_init() {
    call_in_attached_thread([=](auto env) {    
       jclass display_metrics_class = (jclass)env->FindClass("android/util/DisplayMetrics");//WILL NOT WORK! SEE BELOW
       jfieldID density_dpi = env->GetFieldID(display_metrics_class, "densityDpi", "I");
       jfieldID xdpi = env->GetFieldID(display_metrics_class, "xdpi", "F");    
       //And so on...
       ...
    });
```

Next thing which need to be taken into accout is that you can't use **FindClass** function to find custom classes if a callstack didn't started in your java code. So in native threads (no matter attached or not) call to FindClass will cause crash in most cases. You need to find classes in **JNI_OnLoad** and store them in global variables using global java references:

```
jclass globalDisplayMetricsClassRef;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    //
    //previous code here
    //
    auto localRef = env->FindClass("android/util/DisplayMetrics");
    globalDisplayMetricsClassRef = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(localRef);
}
```

So finally we get:

```
navigator_info* navigator_info_init() {
    call_in_attached_thread([=](auto env) {    
       jfieldID density_dpi = env->GetFieldID(globalDisplayMetricsClassRef, "densityDpi", "I");
       jfieldID xdpi = env->GetFieldID(display_metrics_class, "xdpi", "F");    
       //And so on...
       ...
    });
```

**UPDATED:**

Piece of code from ART CheckThread function

```
   // Verify that the current thread is (a) attached and (b) associated with
    // this particular instance of JNIEnv.
    if (soa_.Env() != threadEnv) {
      if (soa_.Vm()->work_around_app_jni_bugs) {
        // If we're keeping broken code limping along, we need to suppress the abort...
        LOG(ERROR) << "APP BUG DETECTED: thread " << *self << " using JNIEnv* from thread " << *soa_.Self();
      } else {
        JniAbortF(function_name_, "thread %s using JNIEnv* from thread %s",
                  ToStr<Thread>(*self).c_str(), ToStr<Thread>(*soa_.Self()).c_str());
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This would work if the thread were not the same. In the error it says: thread Thread[54] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[54]. Therefore JavaVM::GetEnv will return JNI_OK. Any idea whats wrong there?